# drupal_add_js is adding .js file to footer despite me adding 'scope' => 'header'

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to add an external file to the header. To that affect I copied what others have done and used `drupal_add_js();`:

```
  drupal_add_js('somefile.js', [
    'type' => 'external',
    'scope' => 'header',
    'defer' => TRUE,
  ]);
```

But the link still appears in the footer. Of course I've cleared cache and theme registry, but no changes.

How can I add the file to `<head>`?

Comment: Check if your active theme has the region `header` defined in its info file

Comment: @IsmailCherri, yes it does: `regions[header]           = Header`

Comment: Are you sure no other module or theme is adding that same file to the footer somewhere? I'd use `grep -rn 'somefile' /var/www/html/my-drupal-site/` to see if anybody else is trying to include it.

Comment: Check your theme templates. Does your theme have a custom `html.tpl.php`? If so, you may check where it is printing the `$scripts` variable (`<?php print $scripts; ?>`). Is it located within your template's header, or at the bottom of your file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the scope in a `hook_js_alter()` implementation? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x